# Login using httpwebrequest

Tags: httpwebrequest

I am trying to login this website https://www.bewickedcostumes.com/login.php by httpwebrequest.

//Here is GET

```
https://www.bewickedcostumes.com/login.php?open_in_layer=Y&is_ajax_request=Y&keep_https=Y

GET /login.php?open_in_layer=Y&is_ajax_request=Y&keep_https=Y HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bewickedcostumes.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://www.bewickedcostumes.com/login.php
Cookie: store_language=en; __atuvc=22%7C31%2C14%7C32; RefererCookie=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bewickedcostumes.com%2Fproduct.php%3Fproductid%3D18078%26cat%3D%26bestseller%3DY; GreetingCookie=Sammy+Chan; xid_d9db5C_remember=schan%40dropshipinc.com; xid_d9db5=21e18e3615c5ed2ef0597789bcd74746
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 08 Aug 2012 01:49:39 GMT
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2012 02:10:57 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
P3P: CP="NON CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa CONi OUR DELa BUS IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV DEM STA"
Set-Cookie: xid_d9db5=21e18e3615c5ed2ef0597789bcd74746; path=/; domain=www.bewickedcostumes.com; httponly
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Aug 2012 02:10:57 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1220
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

//Here is POST

```
https://www.bewickedcostumes.com/login.php?open_in_layer=Y&is_ajax_request=Y&keep_https=Y

POST /login.php?open_in_layer=Y&is_ajax_request=Y&keep_https=Y HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bewickedcostumes.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://www.bewickedcostumes.com/login.php
Content-Length: 119
Cookie: store_language=en; __atuvc=22%7C31%2C14%7C32; RefererCookie=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bewickedcostumes.com%2Fproduct.php%3Fproductid%3D18078%26cat%3D%26bestseller%3DY; GreetingCookie=Sammy+Chan; xid_d9db5C_remember=schan%40dropshipinc.com; xid_d9db5=21e18e3615c5ed2ef0597789bcd74746
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
xid_d9db5=21e18e3615c5ed2ef0597789bcd74746&is_remember=&mode=login&username=schan%40dropshipinc.com&password=4700Miller
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2012 02:11:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
P3P: CP="NON CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa CONi OUR DELa BUS IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV DEM STA"
Set-Cookie: xid_d9db5=21e7b58ed5b06ad7d5897ad641186f8b; path=/; domain=www.bewickedcostumes.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: GreetingCookie=Sammy+Chan; expires=Mon, 04-Feb-2013 02:11:06 GMT; path=/; domain=www.bewickedcostumes.com; httponly
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Aug 2012 02:11:06 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 193
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

My code can login many site but with this site it doesn't work.

Comment: Check for hidden fields in the form. You're probably missing one.

Answer (score 0):

This part is a unique code that is generated on the Login page by the looks of it:
xid_d9db5=21e18e3615c5ed2ef0597789bcd74746

Scrape the above field & value & add it to the POST request instead of adding the exact code above to your request.

(You may also want to hide your POST data a bit more carefully incase you use them details elsewhere!)